# TensorFlow Multiclass Classifier - <list index out of range> - why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm building a multiclass image classifier in Tensorflow and I keep getting a  error and I am at a loss as to why. Any ideas? Code below is below.]

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from os import getcwd

    images_list = []
    labels_list = []
    with open(filename) as training_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(training_file)
        next(csv_reader)
        for row in csv_reader:
            labels_list.append(row[0])
            images_list.append(np.array(row[1:785], dtype='float64').reshape([28,28]))
    labels = np.array(labels_list, dtype='float64')
    images = np.array(images_list)
    return images, labels

path_sign_mnist_train = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/sign_mnist_train.csv"
path_sign_mnist_test = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/sign_mnist_test.csv"
training_images, training_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_train)
testing_images, testing_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_test)

training_images_extra_dim = np.expand_dims(training_images, axis=3)
testing_images_extra_dim = np.expand_dims(testing_images, axis=3)

training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(training_datagen.flow(training_images_extra_dim, training_labels, batch_size = 10), 
                              epochs=2, 
                              steps_per_epoch=20, 
                              validation_data = validation_datagen.flow(testing_images_extra_dim), 
                              verbose = 1, 
                              validation_steps=len(testing_images/10))
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-b81d91c6a273> in <module>
     20                               validation_data = validation_datagen.flow(testing_images_extra_dim),
     21                               verbose = 1,
---> 22                               validation_steps=len(testing_images/10))
     23 
     24 # model.evaluate(testing_images_extra_dim, testing_labels, verbose=0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1295         shuffle=shuffle,
   1296         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1297         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1298 
   1299   def evaluate_generator(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    321           verbose=0,
    322           mode=ModeKeys.TEST,
--> 323           steps_name='validation_steps')
    324 
    325       if not isinstance(val_results, list):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    263 
    264       is_deferred = not model._is_compiled
--> 265       batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
    266       if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    267         batch_outs = [batch_outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in test_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, reset_metrics)
   1068       outputs = training_v2_utils.test_on_batch(
   1069           self, x, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1070           reset_metrics=reset_metrics)
   1071       outputs = (outputs['total_loss'] + outputs['output_losses'] +
   1072                  outputs['metrics'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in test_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, reset_metrics)
    325       y,
    326       sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 327       output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
    328 
    329   if reset_metrics:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in test_on_batch(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, output_loss_metrics)
    352             sample_weights=sample_weights,
    353             training=False,
--> 354             output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))
    355   if not isinstance(outs, list):
    356     outs = [outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _model_loss(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    164 
    165         if hasattr(loss_fn, 'reduction'):
--> 166           per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])
    167           weighted_losses = losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    168               per_sample_losses,

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I literally don't know why it is doing this and I'd appreciate any insight from someone more knowledgeable with Tensorflow. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're missing a `def function` statement

Comment: Please provide the error stack for more clarification

Comment: Added! Thank you!